# Как конвертировать строку дня и месяца в date формат в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
In [46]: example                                                                                                               
Out[46]: '2802'
```

это строка DDMM имеет формат.
как это можно сконвертировать в date формат питоновский?

```
In [47]: datetime.strptime('2802', '%d%m')                                                                                 
Out[47]: datetime.datetime(1900, 2, 28, 0, 0)
```

потому что так еще и год приписывает мне.

Comment: А какой год должен быть?

Comment: Можете уточнить суть вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект `datetime.datetime` всегда содержит компоненты года, месяца и день месяца. Невозможно создать объект данного типа у которого отсутствует одна из этих компонент.

Пример:

```
In [11]: from datetime import datetime as DT

In [12]: example = '2802'

In [13]: d = DT.strptime(f"{example}{DT.now().year}", "%d%m%Y")

In [14]: d
Out[14]: datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 28, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Как в таком случае разрешить `2902` в не високосном году?

Comment: @Jazzis, это не будет являться реальной датой, следовательно не используйте тип `datetime.datetime`. Или же укажите нужный (високосный) год ...

Answer (score 1):

За основу для функции [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) берется дата/время: `1900-01-01T00:00:00.000`. Любой компонент, не указанный в формате будет взят из значения по умолчанию. Поэтому у вас и получается такой год.